# How to resume timer when app relaunches? Swift 4 ios 11

Tags: ios, swift, timer, notificationcenter

Swift 4 / ios 11

I'm building a very basic notepad app that saves data entered into a text field with a timer that triggers every 4 seconds. I have already figured out the logic to save and load the data after the app quits. It works.

My problem is that my timer doesn't run when the app is force quitted and relaunched. I just want to guarantee that this timer is always running while my app is running.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad() }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        // Logic here to load saved data to text field.

        resumeSaving()
    }

    func resumeSaving() {
         Timer.scheduledTimer(
             timeInterval: 4, 
             target: self, 
             selector: #selector(saveText), 
             userInfo: nil, 
             repeats: true)
    }


    @objc func saveText() {

        // Logic here to save data in text field.

        print("DATA SAVED.")
    }

}
```

Comment: What posts the `resumeSaving` notification? But, why save using a timer?  Why not save when the data is changed?  Or combine the too; when data changes, start a timer for a second. If the data changes before the timer fires, restart it.  Once the timer fires (the user has stopped typing for a second), then save

Comment: I just need my timer to launch and keep running any time the app is open. I don't know how to do all of those things you just said. What will make my timer run forever while the app is open?

Comment: Why have you got that odd notification post thing? Why not just call `resumeSaving`?

Comment: @Paulw11 You're right. I have removed the notificationcenter post but kept the structure basically the same. It still has the same behavior of not resuming when the app is relaunched as described. This is such an easy app and it will be done when i can just guarantee that my timer is always running. Can you help me?

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you help me with the updated code?